# Control shrinking of font size in cases environment

Tags: cases

I'm, using the `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package and I was wondering whether there is a method to control the shrinking of certain elements of it. E.g. when there is a fraction, the elements in the nominator and denominator are shrinked compared to the non-fractional case.

What I would be interested in, is e.g. whether I can enlarge the shrinked element a bit to increase its readability.

Please see:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x=\begin{cases}
\frac{a+b+c}{d+e+f}\\
a+b+c\\
d+e+f
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `dcases` from `mathtools` package. `mathtools` improves upon `amsmath` and provides some extra, cool goodies.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x=\begin{dcases}
\frac{a+b+c}{d+e+f}\\
a+b+c\\
d+e+f
\end{dcases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

If you are tied to `amsmath` some how, use `\displaystyle` just after the `\begin{cases}` line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle              %%5 <--- here
\frac{a+b+c}{d+e+f}\\
a+b+c\\
d+e+f
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Another option will be to use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` as suggested by Werner, but if you have many fractions, this will give you more work ;)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{a+b+c}{d+e+f}\\
a+b+c\\
d+e+f
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me, `\dfrac{}{}` worked perfectly. Thank you very much